# Does smartphone have overvoltage protection?

Tags: voltage, charger, circuit-protection

While charging my galaxy note 3 in the car I noticed that it stop charging. After a while I checked the charger output voltage and was about 8v. Now the phone seem just fine, but I want to know if it has a sort of overvoltage ic since it stop charging in this condition.

Comment: (1) Only the people who have designed your phone can answer this question.  (2) You're lucky that you haven't fried your phone.  Most USB charger ICs are rated for 6V input.

Answer (score 2):

The design details of highly-competitive, mass-market, high-profit consumer goods like high-end smart phones are not typically published for us to discover.

However, it is quite likely that virtually all cell phones have some kind of charging control functionality built in. They will likely not attempt to charge the internal battery if there is insufficient power (voltage and/or current) available from the USB cord. Or if the battery is full or dangerously hot, etc.

BUT, it seems unlikely that many (any?) phones are capable of withstanding more than a slight (perhaps 5%?) over-voltage. It is NOT advisable to assume that ANY phone can withstand more than a slight over-voltage condition.